# WriteConsoleOutputCharacter Access violation

Tags: c++, cmd

I've been trying to execute a command on cmd and i'm using WriteConsoleOutputCharacter. My code is the following:

```
int main( void )
{
    HANDLE hStdout;
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    fun(hStdout,L"file1",L"file2");
    return 0;
}

void fun( HANDLE hConsole,wchar_t* str1,wchar_t* str2 )
{
   COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };    // home for the cursor 
   LPDWORD cCharsWritten=0;
   //LPDWORD cCharsWritten; that was originally
   CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi; 
   DWORD dwConSize;

   if( !GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsole, &csbi ))
   {
      return;
   }

   dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

   std::wstring ss;
   ss=std::wstring(L"cp ")+ str1+std::wstring(L" ")+str2;


   if( !WriteConsoleOutputCharacter( hConsole,        // Handle to console screen buffer 
                                ss.c_str(),     // Character to write to the buffer
                                dwConSize,       // Number of cells to write 
                                coordScreen,     // Coordinates of first cell 
                                cCharsWritten ))// Receive number of characters written
   {
      return;
   }



   if( !GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsole, &csbi ))
   {
      return;
   }


   if( !FillConsoleOutputAttribute( hConsole,         // Handle to console screen buffer 
                                csbi.wAttributes, // Character attributes to use
                                dwConSize,        // Number of cells to set attribute 
                                coordScreen,      // Coordinates of first cell 
                                cCharsWritten )) // Receive number of characters written
   {
      return;
   }

   SetConsoleCursorPosition( hConsole, coordScreen );
}
```

The code compiles fine but t first i was getting an error saying that i was using cCharsWritten without initializing it.So i set it to 0 (LPDWORD cCharsWritten=0;).But then i keep getting

```
Unhandled exception at 0x772c5033 in CpProgrammatically.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00446000.
```

at the line that has the call of WriteConsoleOutputCharacter.
I've tried pretty much anything i could imagine but i can't figure it out.Is there something wrong on the way i use the cCharsWritten variable?Is there a problem with thefact that ss is unicode string?Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter you're passing `cCharsWritten` to is an out parameter that the functions fill when called. You're suppose to pass a pointer to a `DWORD`. What you're passing is a a null pointer.

Change the decleration to:

```
DWORD cCharsWritten = 0;
```

And then pass it in to the functions as `&cCharsWritten` so that the functions can populate the variable with the number of characters written.

Also, make sure that the number of characters in `ss` is equal to the number of characters in `dwConSize`. It looks like the string pointer you're passing in may not have a length equal to `dwConSize`.The using `ss.length()` instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer first of all.Actually i have already tried what you suggested when i saw the WriteConsoleOutputCharacter definition (and i tried it again just now to be sure) but the result is exactly the same,an exception at the same exact point.

Comment: I've added another possible solution.

Comment: Tyrns out dwConSize was the problem as you suggested.I used (DWORD)ss.length() as a parameter instead of it to be sure that there is no problem with the length and everything worked fine. Add this to your answer if you want,and thanks for the help!